# Read OLE object with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, binaryfiles, ole

I have an old application made with Visual Basic that can upload and download documents as OLE objects. That is retrieved to a SQL Server database, which stores them in a varbinary(max) field. However, those bins don't have the same format as regular files, as OLE structured them in its own fashion.

I want to mass download all those docs with a .NET C# app that uses SQL, but I can't find a way to do it. I have tried to copy the binary data in a new file using `SqlDataReader`, `MemoryStream` and `FileStream`, but they interpreted the information straightforward and not in the way OLE structured them. So, the resulting files were corrupted.

Is there a class that can interpret properly this OLE binaries? The old app used an OLE Container component, but they don't exist since a few years.

Comment: Are you talking about [OLE Structured Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369(v=vs.85).aspx) or just straight up `IPersistStorage`?

Comment: If OSS, then assuming you can save the varbinary to disk, you could use a tool like Microsoft's OLE SS viewer from ancient versions of archives or check out this c++ example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379016(v=vs.85).aspx.   There is also a nice write-up [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/24/exploring-the-compound-file-binary-format/)

Comment: I have tried to open a file containing the varbinary with OSS Viewer and it doesn't let me open it, saying it's not a structured storage file.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be for you to create a small file on the DB, dump the resulting varbinary somewhere, and then hope someone know how to open it

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post that never got answered. I am in a similar situation myself in that I need to take images and convert them into OLE Files so that Microsoft Access OLE Bound Frames can read them. I have been researching this for days and have just now discovered the Binary Format that I need i.e. Compound File... or Structured File. They have this Nuget Package available which should accomplish what we both need available here: [OpenMCDF](https://github.com/ironfede/openmcdf/issues/48)

I am still in the process of trying to figure out how to create a compound file from Raw Binary... but feel I am close and will post the resolution when I get it.

UPDATE: The project that I was working on was not supposed to be so involved. Thus I didn't want to waste anymore time with it after already trying different recommendations for a couple days. Thus I ended up creating a complete hack that I never hope to have to repeat. Here are the steps that I used:

1. I set up a form with a maximized window to display each of the images one by one via a timer interval.
2. Between each interval I took programmatic screen shots (Print Screen) of the images, saving them in a separate folder using an identifiable naming convention.

That portion was done all in VBA.

3. Once I had full screen shots in a folder, I then used PhotoShop to then crop all the images in a batch to the exact image sizes.

A hack yes, but it accomplished what I needed... what a pain!

Comment: If it's still of interest: check out the link provided in my new answer.